# create objects from xml which has muitiple classes using JAXB?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have xsd and xml file. first I have generated Java classes from xsd file ,that part has done  and now I have to feed data into objects using xml ? I am using below code , but this is throwing JAXBException.

```
    try {

    File file = new File("D:\\file.xml");
    JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance("com.jaxb.generated");

    Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
    Employee empObj = (Employee) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(file);
    System.out.println(empObj.getName());

  } catch (JAXBException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
```

and here is my xml file which contains two classes :

> ```
>    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
>      <Employee>
>        <name>John</name>            
>        <salary>5000</salary>
>     </Employee>
>     <Customer>
>        <name>Smith</name>
>     </Customer>
> ```

could somebody help me ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The XML document in your question is invalid.  XML documents need to have a single root element.  The first step would be to ensure that your XML document is valid against the XML schema you generated the classes from.

Comment: **@Blaise , @user278064**  : yes I have tried by adding root element in my xml , giving exception as I mentioned in my previous post.                                                                     **here is my xml file :**                                                                 > <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
> <people>
> <employee>
>    <name>John</name>            
>    <country>India</country>
> </employee>
> <customer>
>    <name>steve</name>            
> </customer>
> </people>

Answer (score 3):

**IMPORTANT**

You've an error in your code. You skipped this step:

```
JAXBElement element = (JAXBElement) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(f);
```

Well, I've worked with **JAXB** a long time ago.

However what we used to to in such a sitatuation, was to define an top level element (in Java code or in xsd file) enclosing the other elements.

**e.g.:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<People>
   <Employee>
      <name>John</name>            
      <salary>5000</salary>
      </Employee>
    <Customer>
      <name>Smith</name>
    </Customer>
</People>
```

Java will generate the classes Employee and Customer as children of People.

You could iterate through it in JAXB code in the following way:

```
try {
   File file = new File("D:\\file.xml");
   JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance("com.jaxb.generated");

   Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
   JAXBElement element = (JAXBElement) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(file);
   People people = (People) element.getValue();
   Employee employee = (Employee)people.getChildren().get(0); // the name of the getChildren() methodm may vary
   Customer customer = (Customer)people.getChildren().get(1);
   System.out.println(empObj.getName());
} catch (JAXBException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

You may also want to take a look at this similar question: [iterate-through-the-elements-in-jaxb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11152917/iterate-through-the-elements-in-jaxb/11153059#11153059)

Comment: **I tried with this one but giving exception :**  <Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: com.jaxb.generated.People cannot be cast to javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement at com.jaxb.generated.Unmarshall.unmarshtry2(Unmarshall.java:42) at com.jaxb.generated.Unmarshall.main(Unmarshall.java:14)  Could u solve this **@user278064** ?

Comment: @Kamal: Give attention to what Blaise Doughan said. He's right. you need a singe root element in your xml document (in my example it is called 'People').

Comment: @kamal - Based on the exception you are getting here you just need to change the `element` variable to be of type `People`.